# PHP: How to get a form request which nest a iframe which has other param want to send?

Tags: php, iframe, request

I have a form like the flowing:

```
<form name="pdf" method="post" action="pdf.php">
Name:<input type="text" name="command" id="command" size=20 placeholder="command name">
...
...
<iframe name='rpc' width=700 height=330 frameborder=0 allow-forms>unimportant options that you may forget easilly</iframe>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**In this iframe there will contain the flowing html code:**

```
<textarea name="other" cols=650 rows=20 id="other"></textarea>
```

So how could I get the value of the param **other**(the value of the textarea) in the server side?

It's null when I try to use **$_POST["other"]**;

Comment: This of all, it's $_POST['other'], second you need a html form in order to send the data

Comment: I don't know the second word you said,what's it's meaning?

Comment: You can't just get the value of the textarea in php, you need to send the data by using an html form, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: You mean I need make the textarea nested in an another form?

Comment: Yes, and manager the information on the other page.
Edit : Or you need, by using javascript, copy the value inside the iframe in another field outside the iframe. That would work